# Meteor Blaze.renderWithData how to InsertAfter is it possible?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having a problem to insert a template after and not before a node. For example:

```
//Html looks like this
<div class="questions">
 <div class="question"></div>
 <div class="question"></div>
 <div class="question"></div>
</div>

<template name="question">
  <div class="question"></div>
</div>
<template name="questionExtraInfo">
  <div class="extra"></div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to get the following:

```
<div class="questions">
 <div class="question"></div>
 <div class="extra"></div>
 <div class="question"></div>
 <div class="question"></div>
</div>
```

Calling blaze render inside question event

```
Template.question.events({
  'click .more-details': function () {
     var instance = Template.instance();
     Blaze.renderWithData(Template.questionExtraInfo, {}, document.querySelector('.questions'), instance.find('.question')));
});
```

I can only figure out how render it before or inside how about after?

```
 <div class="extra"></div>
 <div class="question"></div>

 <div class="question"><div class="extra"></div></div>
```

Comment: just added empty div to hold it where needed for now if anyone faces same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to take advantage of reactivity:

Change your `questions` template to:

```
<template name="question">
  <div class="question"></div>
  {{# if shouldIncludeExtra }}
    {{> questionExtraInfo }}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

The above template should be inside an each loop.

Then in your js something like:

```
Template.question.helpers({
  'shouldIncludeExtra': function() {

     // replace 'n' with the actual index. I think `this.index` is 
     // provided within #each blocks, or you can use the new `@each` helper.
    var index = n;

    return Session.get('shouldIncludeExtra' + index);

  }
});
```

Then, in your click event, you set a session var based on the index to `true`:

```
Template.questions.events({
  'click .question': function(e, tpl) {

    var question = e.currentTarget;

    // You can probably come up with something better here..
    var index = $(question).parent().find('> .question').index(question);

    Session.set('shouldIncludeExtra' + index, true);
  }
});
```

Because of reactivity, you would see the inserts right away when you fire the click event.

I realize this doesn't really answer the headline of your question, but it should get you the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the time on answering, Yeah session always for the rescue :) what new index `@each` helper do you have more information? Meteor has a problem where you cannot get the index out of array.  But it's not a problem I can use the _id. I still want to get an answer for the `Blaze.render` it seems like a huge limitation and I wished meteor could be more flexible with the parameters for it. Or there possibly a way I just didn't think of it.

Comment: oh yeah it just came out, check it out: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3560 I'm hoping that you can either pass it as an argument to a helper or most likely it's already available in the data context.